# jQuery Datatables reload from ajax source with new params

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've been through many other questions that seem to be around the same topic, but none have provided a solution, so here goes. I have a Datatable, initialised with the code at: http://jsfiddle.net/26Aqv/

This works.

I then want to refresh the datatable with from the same ajax source but with a new parameter.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Paste the code so we can see.

Comment: I'm utilising Allan Jardine's code:

Comment: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api

Comment: it's the fnReloadAjax part, but I've got nothing to work

Comment: David,

Maybe this [post][1] can help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510552/custom-jquery-datatable-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to hack it to work .... and I do believe it's a hack. If anyone can detail the correct way of doing this I'll happily accept your answer over this:

tblContactsList.fnReloadAjax('/lists/loadMembers/?lid='+aData[0]+'&');